# python read_csv custom separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I try read csv and split data into 2 column. I try went with some regex separators like **(?<=_.*)\s+** but python return "**re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern**". other variants **\s+(?![^_\S+])** give more than 2 columns.

Could someone help me find solution?

> pd.read_csv('out.txt', header=None, sep=r"(?<=_.*)\s+", skiprows=2,
> engine='python', keep_default_na=False)

```
_journal_issue                   23
_journal_name_full               'Physical Chemistry and Chemical Physics'
_journal_page_first              9197
_journal_page_last               9204
_journal_paper_doi               10.1039/c3cp50853f
_journal_volume                  15
_journal_year                    2013
_chemical_compound_source        'Corrosion product'
_chemical_formula_structural     'Fe3 O4'
_chemical_formula_sum            'Fe3 O4'
_chemical_name_mineral           Magnetite
_chemical_name_systematic        'Iron diiron(III) oxide'
_space_group_crystal_system      cubic
_space_group_IT_number           227
_space_group_name_Hall           'F 4d 2 3 -1d'
_space_group_name_H-M_alt        'F d -3 m :1'
_cell_angle_alpha                90
_cell_angle_beta                 90
_cell_angle_gamma                90
_cell_formula_units_Z            8
_cell_length_a                   8.36
_cell_length_b                   8.36
_cell_length_c                   8.36
_raman_determination_method      experimental
_[local]_chemical_compound_color Black
_[local]_chemical_compound_state Solid
_raman_measurement_device.location 'IMMM Maine university'
_raman_measurement_device.company 'HORIBA Jobin Yvon'
_raman_measurement_device.model  T64000
_raman_measurement_device.optics_type microscope
_raman_measurement_device.microscope_system dispersive
_raman_measurement_device.microscope_objective_magnification 100
_raman_measurement_device.microscope_numerical_aperture 0.90
_raman_measurement_device.excitation_laser_type Argon-Krypton
_raman_measurement_device.excitation_laser_wavelength 514
_raman_measurement_device.configuration simple
_raman_measurement_device.resolution 3
_raman_measurement_device.power_on_sample 2
_raman_measurement_device.direction_polarization unoriented
_raman_measurement_device.spot_size 0.8
_raman_measurement_device.diffraction_grating 600
_raman_measurement.environment   air
_raman_measurement.environment_details
_raman_measurement.temperature   300
_raman_measurement.pressure      100
_raman_measurement.background_subtraction no
_raman_measurement.background_subtraction_details
_raman_measurement.baseline_correction no
_raman_measurement.baseline_correction_details
```

Comment: why a simple "white space" separator is not enough?

Comment: ^: `delim_whitespace=True` in addition with `quotechar="'"` should do the job?

Comment: because this solution give in output more than 2 column. I have " " in 2nd column: 'Physical Chemistry and Chemical Physics'.

Comment: @triestromioluki: that is the job of `quotechar="'"`. Any space character enclosed in a pair of simple quotes will not be used as a delimiter.

Comment: oh my bad. yes looks like this work. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    "out.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True, quotechar="'", keep_default_na=False
)
```

Result for your sample:

```
                                                    0                                        1
0                                      _journal_issue                                       23
1                                  _journal_name_full  Physical Chemistry and Chemical Physics
2                                 _journal_page_first                                     9197
...
46  _raman_measurement.background_subtraction_details                                         
47             _raman_measurement.baseline_correction                                       no
48     _raman_measurement.baseline_correction_details
```

Answer (score 0):

As per pandas documentation, [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can provide `sep` as only string and string like `r"<String>"` is usually used for Raw string.

What I would recommend is first loop through file and replace all delimiter to a common delimiter and then feed file to pandas read_csv.

---

Apparently, Above answer is not true. [jjramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643973/jjramsey) from comment below has mentioned it perfectly how it's wrong.

> In the [Pandas documentation for read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), it says, "separators longer than 1 character and different from `\s+` will be interpreted as regular expressions." So, no separators are not always fixed strings. Also, `r` is a perfectly good prefix for strings used for regular expressions, since it avoids having to escape backslashes.

Comment: In the [Pandas documentation for `read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), it says, "separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular expressions." So, no separators are not always fixed strings. Also, `r` is a perfectly good prefix for strings used for regular expressions, since it avoids having to escape backslashes.

Comment: Nice one. Learned something today. Adding your comment to the answer.